# How to print a SharePoint List Infopath form / How to display a column item in the form

Tags: list, printing

I am struggling trying to do this:

1. Printing the forms: I have a SharePoint list that contains all request forms filled by users. When I click in "view item", it displays the filed form. However, the content in some fields is not fully displayed, which makes the print screen option not viable. Is there an easy way to print those forms? (it is an Infopath form).
2. For this same list, I have a column that generates the unique number for each form (in sequence). When I click "view item" to display the form, the content in this column (the unique number) is not present in the form (since it is generated after user fills the form). Is there a way to display this content when displaying the filled form?

Thank you!